# Accessing template static function

Tags: rust

Using rust, I'm trying to access a generic's static function.

```rust
#![allow(unused)]

struct Bar;
impl Bar{
    fn foo(){}
}

struct Qux;
impl Qux{
    fn run<T>() {
        T::foo();
    }
}

fn main() {
    Qux::run::<Bar>();
}
```

This however doesn't work, because:

```bash
 T::foo();
   |            ^^^ function or associated item not found in `T`
```

What is the idiomatic way of doing this?
I've set up a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=005ad3afa2a726db9c917e542a431127) to simplify debugging.

Comment: Rust is unlike C++, in Rust, calling a method of a generic requires a trait bound.

Comment: `fn run<T:Bar>() {`

Comment: @hkBst It doesn't work, `Bar` is a struct, not a trait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a template, **it is a generic function**. You cannot use a method over an object if you do not know if that object have that method. Rust checks all this in compile time.
The rusty way would be to create a `trait` and the **constrain** the type to that `trait`:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]

trait Foo {
    fn foo() {}
}

struct Bar;
impl Foo for Bar {}

struct Qux;
impl Qux {
    fn run<T: Foo>() {
        T::foo();
    }
}

fn main() {
    Qux::run::<Bar>();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6185eb4d353a8eee384b4e0cb7a89d89)